# Swift tableview load more data

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am implementing a method to load more results returned from my sql server when the table view reaches the bottom.

The issue I am facing is that the getData() method is called in a loop and I cant figure out why.

The log repeats the output below until the application is terminated:

> Index Path:12
>   Last Element: 12
>   Index Path:12
>   Last Element: 12

I suspect its one of those which is creating the loop but I can't work out what to change.

Any assistance with this is much appreciated

This is my willDisplayCell method:

```html
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = id.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {

            print("Index Path:\(indexPath.row)")
            print("Last Element: \(lastElement)")
                limitf = "\(lastElement)"
                getData()
        }
    }
```

and the function I am using to get the data:

```html
 func getData(){

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let userID =  defaults.string(forKey: "id")

        if(limitf == ""){
        id.removeAll()
        firstname.removeAll()
        lastname.removeAll()
        fbid.removeAll()
        image.removeAll()
        totalratings.removeAll()
        mobile.removeAll()
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.****/getapplications.php?&jobid=\(jobid)&limitf=\(limitf)")
       // print(url!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as! URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let urlContent = data {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        var i = 0
                        while i < jsonResult.count {

                            self.id.append(jsonResult[i]["id"]! as! String)
                            self.firstname.append(jsonResult[i]["firstname"]! as! String)
                            self.lastname.append(jsonResult[i]["lastname"]! as! String)
                            self.fbid.append(jsonResult[i]["fbid"]! as! String)
                            self.image.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)
                            self.totalratings.append(jsonResult[i]["totalratings"]! as! String)
                            self.mobile.append(jsonResult[i]["mobile"]! as! String)

                            i = i + 1
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON serialization failed")
                }
            } else {
                print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        task.resume()



    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a flag to detect when `getData` is running so that it simply returns if the flag indicates that the process is already running? This way, if you have `getData` being called twice in rapid succession, it will still run only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 12 records on the server, and the 12th record is visible on screen, then every time it is displayed, getData() will be called. The server will probably return no more records (so the count will remain 12) and the call to .reloadData() will cause the 12 records to be displayed again,  which will call getData() again on the 12th,  and so on ...

You should not call reloadData() when no new records were received.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getData() in willDisplayCell for the last cell being displayed and then clear the contents and reload the table. This means the last cell is always called to reload the data - which is why it keeps looping.

What you should do is detect as you are doing when the last row is loaded, but when you call getData(), rather than clearing out the existing data, you should append the new data rows and use insertRowsAtIndexPaths to update your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you load self.tableView.reloadData() in getData(). 
This method means it will run those methods in tableView delegate once again.
As long as you put self.tableView.reloadData() away, this loop will end.